# Beginner on website framework selection with Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, nuxt.js

I just started learning Vue.js, Vue router, vuex and Nuxt.js and had followed through some tutorial codes. I am a scientific researcher and building a website database which mainly serves these requirements:

- the server can fetch data from MYSQL and display its relative info, e.g, a gene and its relatives
- A user can upload a file, then the server uses the file as an input, runs a Linux program and parses the result to display on the website. The app should be able to monitor status when executing the program from the system.
- I don't have CDN requirement and the website has to be hosted on a single Linux server from the internal institution.

I saw some backend framework options when initializing a Nuxt.js app, like default Nuxt.js(seems without a backend server?), express.js, koa, etc.

Should I include the express.js to serve the backend processing? Or simply default Nuxt.js can do the job?  What confuses me is that Nuxt.js recommend not using other backend server and better generate static websites, but my app seems need to deal a lot of backend data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of an obscure question, but maybe this will help.. More than likely if you are wanting to generate a site with Nuxt, you are looking at needing it to be rendered outside of your Vue Spa. Nuxt is a library that works with Vue to make a "static site" or server side rendered site. This helps for things like Google Bot (SEO) etc...

If you are looking at creating a site that has an API to store data, and using Vue as your frontend framework, I would suggest a MEVN (Mongo, Express, Vue, Node) setup or a Laravel (PHP - Laravel backend, Vue frontend) setup and using each respective one as an API for your data and getting that data from your database.

MEVN - https://github.com/UncleRemus/mevn-boilerplate

Laravel - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/frontend#writing-vue-components

Hope this helps you out.